# Как обернуть все дочерние элементы Div в Массив в JavaScripte

Tags: javascript, html

Как обернуть все дочерние элементы `id=teno` в один массив? - на JavaScriptе.

То есть `text1[0], text2[1], text3[2]`.

```
 <div class="col-12" id="teno">
     <div id="text1"> <h1>Text1</h1> </div>
    <div id="text2"> <h1>Text2</h1> </div>
    <div id="text3"> <h1>Text3</h1> </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: `let arr = [...teno.children];`

Comment: Спасибо большое